# Nginx serving application and ExpressJS just as backend

Tags: express, nginx

I think it's pretty common to use `nginx` to proxy connections to ExpressJS, so all is done through ExpressJS.

I was thinking, why not use nginx to server the application since it's more simple to setup things like rewrites and let ExpressJS as backend only and then the application communicate to ExpressJS directly on 3000 port.

Is it a bad idea? If not, how often people does this ?

Comment: This is pretty common. The only issue is that node has to be set up to handle CORS.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Using same domain, different ports only is considered a CORS?

Comment: Yup........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034489/properly-understanding-cors-with-same-host-different-port-security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very common. But having your front end code directly talk to the node server adds  complexity.

You have to handle CORS issues on the node server, including preventing cross site form submissions. See here [Properly Understanding CORS with Same Host / Different Port & Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034489/properly-understanding-cors-with-same-host-different-port-security).

SSL is also going to be a bit more complicated. You'll need a wild card certificate.

However, there are some big advantages to using something like ngnix to host your assets. In addition to the ones you enumerated, it sets you up to go serverless. You can host your app out of an S3 bucket our through another content delivery network.